# Remove square brackets from list C#

Tags: c#, json

This is my code.

```
public static List<MyList> GetConfigurationJson()
{
     List<MyList> Informations = new List<MyList>();

     MyList CustomerLog = new MyList
        {
            ChannelName = "HR",
            SubscriptionKey = "001",
                        Tenant = new Tenant()
                        {
                            CustomerId = "2001",
                            TenantId = "2551",
                            TenantName = "Hello"
                        }
        };

    Informations.Add(CustomerLog);

    return Informations;
}
```

My output is like this.

```
[
  {
    "channelName": "HR",
    "subscriptionKey": "001",
    "tenant": {
      "customerId": "dhh-e98391962001",
      "tenantId": "391962551",
      "tenantName": "dffg.com"
    }
  }
]
```

I want to remove this square brackets from here. I tried to convert this to Json. But I need output as below format for swagger.

[image: output]

Comment: any reason for using a List here?

Comment: Name your classes correctly, `MyList` is terrible

Comment: `MyList` is a confusing type name for something that isn't a list!

Comment: @phuzi Actually i created a sample for post this question. MyList should be channel. Thanks for reminder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want to return the Channel Object instead of a List. Try this:

```
public static Channel GetConfigurationJson()
{
    MyList CustomerLog = new MyList
                {
                    ChannelName = "HR",
                    SubscriptionKey = "001"
                    Tenant = new Tenant()
                    {
                        CustomerId = "2001",
                        TenantId = "2551",
                        TenantName = "Hello"
                    }
                } 
    return CustomerLog;
}
```